# Porque hay veces que no envia correos mi aplicacion?

Tags: java, gmail, javamail

Buen dia, escribo porque tengo inconvenientes con mi aplicacion en java, el inconveniente que tiene es que hay veces en las cuales se envian los correos sin inconvenientes (estoy usando javax.mail.jar y activation.jar) y de un momento a otro deja de enviar correos porque no se conecta satisfactoriamente al correo.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("*mi correo*", "*mi contraseña*");
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,authenticator);
        session.setDebug(true);

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


            if (sub=="en seguimiento") {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("*direccion de destino1*"));
            }else{
                for (int i = 0; i < co.length; i++) {
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(co[i]));
                }
            }


            sub="Soporte "+sub;

            message.setSubject(sub);

            message.setText(text);

            Transport.send(message);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,"Correo enviado correctamente");

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

estoy usando tambien el debugger de la clase session y me arroja los siguientes errores:

> DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465,
>   isSSL false com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect
>   to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   recurso.EnviarCorreo.enviarCorreo(EnviarCorreo.java:59)   at
>   modelo.GestorSoporte.registrarSoporte(GestorSoporte.java:46)  at
>   controlador.SoporteControl.actionPerformed(SoporteControl.java:61)    at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)   at
>   java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
>     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)   at
>   java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540)    at
>   com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359)
>     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175)
>     ... 44 more

ya he intentado cambiando las librerias, el servidor de envio de correos, el puerto se envio ya habilite las conexiones desde aplicaciones desconocidas en mi correo y aun asi no me deja de aparecer el error, como comento esto sucede en repetidas ocasiones y me gustaria solucionarlo para que no se presente mas este inconveniente, muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: te lo hace algunas veces solamente?

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag muy seguido de hecho, como comento, esta funcionando enviando correos sin inconvenientes y de un momento a otro sin siquiera modificar el codigo empieza a fallar arrojando el error que describi y despues de un rato funciona normal, sino que quisiera arreglar el inconveniente porque la app enviara probablemente 1 correo (minimo) por hora.

Comment: Consulta [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1990454/5587982), la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1990581/5587982) marcada como aceptada y la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1990674/5587982) que se propone como solución completa.